# Creating a new system

Tags: indie-rpg

I've got a question: I would like to create my own RPG system but base it on Fantasy Flight dice system.

Can I do it and then publish this system, or FFG can sue me for that?

Comment: There's thin line between inspiration and derivative works. Only your lawyer can answer this question, and only after you will show him your work. For now it's unanswerable, sadly. Except the standard "anyone can sue anyone else, the real question is if you can afford the cost of legal proceedings before you go bankrupt".

Comment: I've heard it said that in the United States at least, you can't copyright game rules, only the implementation of those rules, which is why retroclones based on D&D are allowed. However, I'm not a lawyer. You'd probably need to talk to a copyright lawyer or someone well versed in that topic to be certain; perhaps [Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/) can answer your question.

Comment: I've marked this as a dupe of an existing question, as I believe this should be wholly covered by that. If it doesn't, please clarify for us the distinction. That should hopefully cover whatever details others found needed.

Comment: But where are our manners? Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!